# Update a row's unique field and set the value in the existing row to null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a unique varchar column. This column contains android and iOS device IDs to which I can send push notifications.

If a user logs into their account on another device which id is already present on another row I would like the original account's column to be set to null and the new row to instead contain the device ID.

Is there a statement that will achieve this for me or must I create a transaction that first checks for the value in the table and sets it to null before updating the new record? Obviously, if I can do this in one statement it would be preferable.

Edit to clarify a few things based on your answers & comments:

What I currently have for a query is:

```
UPDATE gp_login SET deviceOS='$OS', device_id='$deviceID', id_updated_at=NOW() WHERE email='$email'
```

Of course this fails when a device_id already exists for another row in the table.

I played with using REPLACE but it deletes rows and there is other data in the rows which should not be lost.

The device ID although unique, is not the primary key for the table.
The table is a list of mobile user accounts which log into a mobile app service. Their device ID is updated into their account rows but is still unique. I want to update a row's device ID even if the same device ID exists for another user - I'd just like it to be set to null there first to fulfil the unique constraint.

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: Can you provide a rough example to guide you correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated the question.

Comment: Why is that field unique?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I didn't want a situation in which the same notification would be sent to a device_id multiple times. I will have a think about what removing the constraint would mean for my service as it may be the case that it might not be a concern in reality. Thanks.

Comment: You probably need two tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

There is no single statement in MySQL that does both an `update` and an `insert`.  The one option that you have is an `insert` trigger.  You can write a trigger that will remove the previous device ids.

However, I'm not certain that this is a good idea.  Why would you want to forget previous device ids?  It seems like they could be useful, for instance, if an anonymous user comes to the site but doesn't log in.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.

Please see the updated question as I think I wasn't clear enough before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set previous ids to NULL before adding new row

```
Update table
set
device_id=null
where accounted=your_account_id and device_id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your design. You want to be able to insert multiple rows per device. But at the same time you want the device ID to be unique. That doesn't really make sense. You probably need two different tables. One will have the unique index and contain only currently logged-in users. In the other table you save the "data in the rows which should not be lost.". Which is actually a log table. Since the device ID isn't unique in the log table, you don't need to delete it - So you keep even more information.